How to rigorously prove that a double integral exists for every subdivision of a region?
How to rigorously prove that a double integral exists for every subdivision of a region?
I am trying to understand the rigorous proof of the existence of a double integral for a function ( f(x, y) ) over a region ( R ). Specifically, I would like to know how to show that the double integral (i mean the limit):
exists for every partition of the region ( R ) and not just for a particular partition.
I understand that this might involve partitioning the region into smaller subregions, calculating the Riemann sums, and then taking the limit as the partition gets finer. However, I’m not sure about the details of how to rigorously prove that the double integral exists in this sense.
Some points I am specifically interested in:

Partitioning the region: How do we define a partition rigorously for an arbitrary region ( R )? Does the partition need to have any specific properties (e.g., does it need to be a refinement of previous partitions)?

Riemann sums and limits: How do we prove that the limit of the Riemann sums exists as the norm of the partition tends to zero?

what is a closed region

Existence for all subdivisions: How do we prove that this holds for every subdivision, and not just for specific ones?


Any clarification, references to specific theorems, or suggestions on how to approach this proof would be greatly appreciated!
Tags: double-integral, riemann-integral, real-analysis, partition, rigorous-proof

I don't understand what you mean by "The limit existing to every partition." If you understand well the definition of Riemann Sums and the integral as the limit of Riemann Sums in the case of real valued functions defined on intervals, then the process is pretty much the same to double integral, however you would need to define the integral for a rectangle to, later on, define in more general regions.

The Riemann integral in $\Bbb R^2$ is not defined for all regions by partitions. Instead it is defined for regions of the form $[a,b] \times [c,d]$, where the partitions are products of partitions of the two intervals. That definition is then extended to arbitrary regions $R$ by  $$\int_R f dA = \int_{\Bbb R^2} f(x)\mathbf 1_R(x),dA$$ where $\mathbf 1_R$ is the characteristic function of $R$: $$\mathbf 1_R(x)= \begin{cases}1&x\in R\0&x\notin R\end{cases}$$
